# JavaFX - Adding nodes to ScrollPane with correct scrolling direction

Tags: javafx-2, scrollpane

I have a ScrollPane in my scene and would like to add a series of Nodes to it. The exact amount must be dynamic. I've been testing the concept with Label nodes and can successfully add as many Labels as I want to the content of the ScrollPane (currently a VBox).

My problem is figuring out how to allow the user to scroll normally through the ScrollPane full of Nodes. The content matches pace with the scrollbar; that is, when I scroll down, the content moves down. I scroll up, the content scrolls up. So if I have 10 Labels, only five of which are currently visible, the instinctive action to see the other five would be to scroll down. Unfortunately, this just moves the entire content down, exposing empty space up top and hiding more of the Labels.

I can post some sample code if that helps, but the gist of my plan of attack is this:

```
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
VBox content = new VBox();
sp.setContent(content);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label("Label " + i);
    content.setPrefHeight(content.getPrefHeight() + label.getPrefHeight());
    content.getChildren().add(label);
}
```

Because I use a VBox, the Labels are stacked (in the Y axis) atop one another, which is what I want. As more Labels are added, the ScrollBar needs to reflect the increased size of the VBox.
I've tried a few approaches to get this to work, including `ScrollPane.setVmax()` method, which is ok, but I still have the issue of the scroll direction moving the content in the wrong direction. I've also tried an `EventHandler` and `EventFilter` to modify values accordingly, still without solving the problem of scrolls not moving the content in the right direction.

The answer seems so simple, yet the it continues to evade me, even after many long hours messing around with the code.

EDIT:

jewelsea's suggestion of using a `ListView` solved my problem. However, I remain curious as to why using a `ScrollPane` did not fare so well. Additionally, I've run into odd behavior with the `ListView` implementation: I use a button to manually add a new `Label` to the view. Every now and then, the view will freeze up after adding a new `Label`. It locks up for a few seconds before either updating the scroll position or displaying the newly added `Label`. I don't know if this is because there are about 20 or so `Label` instances being managed by the view or if something more insidious is at play.

Comment: Any reason not to use a `ListView` to implement this? I think it may take care of these kind of issues for you.

Comment: @jewelsea, you solved it! I'm always amazed at how the majority of these problems seem so large yet their solution is so simple. I was able to use a `ListView<Label>` and can still apply the effects and transforms (to animate adding a `Label`). Through CSS, I was able to remove the padding and colors to simulate an empty area that remained scrollable as more content was added.

However, I am still curious to know why the `ScrollPane` was scrolling so oddly, and why no amount of tweaking seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the scrollpane issues, I know what you're looking to do is possible because I'm doing something very similar. Based on the code snippet you gave above I would suggest trying few things...

- Give the ScrollPane a preferred height and width to follow.
- Don't give the content VBox any height sizing preference as it will grow with its contents. There should be no need to update its height after adding content either.
- Use the VBox's *setAlignment* method to align its contents either **TOP_LEFT**, **TOP_CENTER**, or **TOP_RIGHT**.
- Be cautious when using the *getPrefHeight()* method because if you haven't used *setPrefHeight()* beforehand I believe it will return **-1**.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: While it isn't in the snippet above, I was setting the ScrollPane's dimensions explicitly (in Scene Builder and my code). I also toggled between messing with the content's height, and I did have an alignment specified. I was able to add things fine after some more messing around, but I still couldn't scroll the way I wanted to.